# Windows Docker Container has no NAT IP Address. Cannot access container locally

Tags: docker, dockerfile, windows-networking

First to be clear, my docker container has an IP address under `NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge`. That IP is `172.17.0.2`

However I cannot access the container via `http://172.17.0.2:3000/` after running it with `docker run -p 3000:3000 node:8.10.0`

My research shows its rough working with docker locally on windows. In following this short guide: https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/

I come across using the network NAT IP address. I see this recommended a few places. But that section of my `docker inspect` does not exist at all.
It returns:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {                                                                            
 "Bridge": "",                                                                               
 "SandboxID": "0c81d8f7ce5bcba70ec0487bbfe91bc6f221e29d9378c33708fac78d0ae47d3e",            
 "HairpinMode": false,                                                                       
 "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",                                                                 
 "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,                                                                
 "Ports": {                                                                                  
     "3000/tcp": [                                                                           
         {                                                                                   
             "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",                                                            
             "HostPort": "3000"                                                              
         }                                                                                   
     ]                                                                                       
 },                                                                                          
 "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0c81d8f7ce5b",                                         
 "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,                                                               
 "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,                                                             
 "EndpointID": "bbe5f42a5b53c001bd3c2852bc6b22976fb9bab2afcb88b30f6660d7662f526f",           
 "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",                                                                    
 "GlobalIPv6Address": "",                                                                    
 "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,                                                                   
 "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",                                                                  
 "IPPrefixLen": 16,                                                                          
 "IPv6Gateway": "",                                                                          
 "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",                                                          
 "Networks": {                                                                               
     "bridge": {                                                                             
         "IPAMConfig": null,                                                                 
         "Links": null,                                                                      
         "Aliases": null,                                                                    
         "NetworkID": "0af66a62bc57ce25491c82f5a13d947ca79f5a879f3c1a6db40a90233eeb04f8",    
         "EndpointID": "bbe5f42a5b53c001bd3c2852bc6b22976fb9bab2afcb88b30f6660d7662f526f",   
         "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",                                                            
         "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",                                                          
         "IPPrefixLen": 16,                                                                  
         "IPv6Gateway": "",                                                                  
         "GlobalIPv6Address": "",                                                            
         "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,                                                           
         "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",                                                  
         "DriverOpts": null                                                                  
     }                                                                                       
 }
```

As you can see the NAT section is missing entirely. I cant find anything online that mentions why or how to resolve. I was hoping it missing would be a good thing and make it easier to connect. Alas it does not. Any help is appreciated. Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.10.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js", "assets"]
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: When you publish a port, you access it by contacting the host on that published port. You should not be accessing containers directly unless from another container on a shared user created network.

Comment: @BMitch correct, so localhost:3000 should be working, right? It's not. I've followed all of the steps I've seen on many 'dockerize a node app' tutorials and they all end the same. unable to reach the website served at port 3000

Comment: If it wasn't clear i'm running docker on windows, all images and containers are on my windows machine.

Comment: Is `$DOCKER_HOST` set to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known bug under docker windows. It is fixed in 19.03. So try updating your docker engine.

Comment: Is there a link to the issue where this was documented and fixed? I'm on 19.03.4 and am having this or a very similar issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue... any idea?